# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod Unauthorized even though credentials work in Postman

Tags: powershell, rest

I used to have a call to a REST API that worked fine like this:

```
$r = 'myRestApiEndpoint'

$h = @{
maxauth = 'myBase64EncodedString'
}

$r = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $h
```

Because of changes in my ITSM tool, the way authorization works has changed a little. Instead of using maxauth we will now use **authorization** as a header and we need to provide the word 'Basic' in front of the base64 string, like this:

```
$r = 'myRestApiEndpoint'

$h = @{
authorization = 'Basic myBase64EncodedString'
}

$r = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $h
```

When I use this new header in Postman I get a 200 OK response fetching me data. But when I run the above code piece in Powershell I get the following response:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At H:\Connectors\ITSM\connector.ps1:61 char:6
$r = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $h
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) 
[Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I don't understand why I get this error. I think the authorization is not send correctly to the API service. I also tried without the word "Basic" but it gives me the same result.

Why am I seeing this error message?

**EDIT**

I changed my code to a more readable format:

```
$base64 = 'myBase64'
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"

$h = @{
    authorization = $basicAuthValue
    maxauth = $base64
}
```

This works. If I comment the row with **maxauth** out, the 401 unauthorized error occurs. Also if I print $basicAuthValue then it shows the same Basic myBase64 that works in Postman. Same endpoint, everything.

**EDIT**
Found the issue. When I mentioned changes in my ITSM tool in my OP, I meant a migration. Instead, they created another environment instead of migrating the existent one. This new environment had all users, but with a default username. Therefore my base64 was always wrong.

I also mentioned that the query worked in Postman. I tried the query again today and it failed. I think postman maybe used my maxauth from a cache maybe? Not sure why it worked before.

Answer (score 1):

Your API seems to require header `MaxAuth` = `Base64encode("<username>:<password>")` like [IBM MAM](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/configuring-maximo-authentication) requires, and it does not care [normal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) `Authorization` header as defined in standard.

So you can

```
$apiUsername = 'username'
$apiPassword = 'password'

$apiHeaders = @{
    MaxAuth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$($apiUsername):$($apiPassword)"))
}

$apiResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $apiHeaders # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So the requests from Postman and Powershell are obviously different. In those cases I would simply compare the requests, e.g. with [responsler](https://www.responsler.com/) (just choose a hostname and do your requests both from Postman and Powershell to compare the requests in detail).

401 can theoretically have other reasons than a "wrong" auth header. Therefore, it is important to know how the requests look like.

Comment: Thanks for this reference. I'll check it tomorrow when I am able to.